# How do I create a simple page of homework in LaTeX?

Tags: formatting

I've been frustrated with using Microsoft Word for typing out equations, so I've decided to switch over to LaTeX to write all of my homework with. I've never used LaTeX before to typeset anything, so I'm a little overwhelmed right now.

At the moment, all I need to do is make a simple document that has the following format:

> My Name
>  My ID Number
>  Class Name
>
> ### Document Title
>
> Multiple paragraphs of double-spaced text will go here.
>
> Another paragraph of text.

How can I typeset this simple document in LaTeX?

Comment: Relatively recently I was exactly like you. There is already an answer below, but I'll try to predict what is going to happen very soon: you will find yourself frustrated and looking for ways to create tables, add (and trim, and scale, and rotate) images, set up multiple columns and variety of other customizations and tweaks. So to avoid all this I started with "LaTeX Beginners guide" by Stefan Kottwiz (no need to read thoroughly, just things related to your work area) and "The TEXbook" by Donald Knuth is another excellent example.

Comment: Check out this link: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/ ... It's a huge help on your everyday work with LaTeX

Comment: I would suggest you to start with a basic introduction to LaTeX; perhaps the [`lshort`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lshort) document.

Comment: Another good option to read is ["LATEX for Word Processor Users"](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/info/latex4wp/latex4wp.pdf).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass[parskip=full]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
My Name\\
My ID Number\\
Class Name

\Huge\textbf{Document Title}

\doublespacing
\normalsize

\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it looks more straightforward and does not have as many advanced features that I don't really understand yet.

Comment: @user1494845 ` \\ ` should never be used unless absolutely necessary. I suggest you look into `\Author` The OP will not have to go through `hbox` error in the future, if they do not use ` \\ `

Answer (score 5):

Here's one possibility:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\onehalfspacing

\makeatletter
\def\idnumber#1{\def\@idnumber{#1}}
\def\classname#1{\def\@classname{#1}}
\def\makeheader{%
\par\noindent{\large\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
\@author \\
\@idnumber \\
\@classname
\end{tabular}}\par\nobreak\vskip20pt
\noindent{\bfseries\LARGE\@title\par}\bigskip
}
\makeatother

\author{My Name}
\idnumber{34567312}
\classname{General Topology}
\title{Closure of a set}

\begin{document}
\makeheader

\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```

The first page of the resulting document:

[image]

I defined some commands `\idnumber` and `\classname` for the ID number and the class name; the `\makeheader` command typesets the information for these two commands and `\author`, `\title` with the desired formatting.

The [`setspace`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/setspace) package was used to change the interline spacing.

The `lipsum` package was only used to generate text for the example.